# Removing non-input parameters when using functools LRU cache?

Tags: python

I have a function that uses functools LRU cache, but I want to pass in some non-input parameters e.g. "a"

```
import functools
import random

def foo(d, a):
    @functools.lru_cache()
    def bar(d):
        random.seed(d)
        nonlocal a
        a = []
        s = 0
        for i in range(100):
            r = random.random()
            a.append(r)
            s += r
        if s < 50:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return bar(d)
```

But when I use these functions, "a" is not changed:

```
a = []
print(foo(random.randint(0, 100), a))
print(a)
```

What's going on? Also is this the right way to use functools, nested?

**Update**

I used this in the end i.e. with global and without foo:

```
@functools.lru_cache()
def bar(d):
    global a
    random.seed(d)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not change `a` because you are redefining it in the function. You are basically doing this:

```
def foo(a):
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    return a

a = []
foo(a)
```

So the outer `a` will remain as empty list after the function call. You may say but I'm using `nonlocal` keyword so I should be referencing to the original `a`. In fact, you are referencing to the *parameter*. So the effect is same as above code. If you run below code with and without `nonlocal` you can see what's going on:

```
def foo(a):
    def bar():
        # nonlocal a
        a = [1, 2, 3]
        print("bar", a)
    bar()
    print("foo", a)

a = []
foo(a)
print("global", a)
```

Outputs:

```
bar [1, 2, 3]
foo []
global []
```

And when you use `nonlocal a`:

```
bar [1, 2, 3]
foo [1, 2, 3]
global []
```

What you can do in your function is delete `nonlocal a` statement since it does not have any effect on the outer `a` and replace `a = []` with `a.clear()`.

Comment: Gotcha, so you have to be careful not to re-initialise, as that would create a new list.